# cannot get chat dialogs with backend authonticatioin "Forbidden. Need user." errror

Tags: javascript, quickblox

I am using js sdk for quickblox. I create a session on the backend server:

> https://api.quickblox.com/session.json
>   get token from result
>   then in my js

```
QB.init(token, apiId);
QB.getSession(function(err, res) {
    QB.chat.connect({userId: user.id, password: user.pass}, function(err, roster) {
        QB.chat.dialog.list(null, function(err, resDialogs) {});
    });
});
```

and I always have the "Forbidden. Need user" error. I was thinking that  B.chat.connect should set current user, but it seems to be I wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I added DB.login and everything works right now.

```
QB.login({login: user.login, password: user.pass}, function(err, res) {
    QB.getSession(function (err, res) {
        QB.chat.connect({userId: user.id, password: user.pass}, function (err, roster) {
            QB.chat.dialog.list(null, function (err, resDialogs) {
            });
        });
    });
});
```